# Get Iframe Src content using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

I have added to an html file: maintenance.html an iframe:

```
<iframe name="iframe_name" src="maintenance_state.txt" frameborder="0" height="40" allowtransparency="allowtransparency" width="800" align="middle" ></iframe>
```

And I want to get the content of the src file maintenance_state.txt using Python and Selenium. 
I'm locating the iframe element using:

```
maintain = driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name")
```

However maintain.text is returning an empty value. 
How can I get the text written in maintenance_state.txt file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by getting the content of "maintenance_state.txt" , means reading the file?

Comment: let's say the content of maintenance_state.txt is "testing state". I want to store that content into a variable. str=  "testing state"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `src` element, navigate to it and get the `page_source`:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

src = driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name").get_attribute("src")
url = urljoin(base_url, src)

driver.get(url)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 13):

As some sites' scripts stop the iframe from working properly if it's loaded as the main document, it's also worth knowing how to read the iframe's source without needing to issue a separate `driver.get` for its URL:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name"))
print(driver.page_source)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

The last line is needed only if you want to be able to do something else with the page afterwards.